# Has anyone edited the blender source code to enable unlimited undo's?

Tags: modeling, source-code

I was looking for a method that removes the undo cap, some said to make the count 0 which was so wrong, 0 just removes undo's that should have been made more clear, i lost an enitre file cuz of that, so I read that the only way to get unlimited undoes is if you edit the source code and recompile, I'm not a software developer, and I barely can write c# in unity, so i was wondering if someone already as done this or have any guides or if this is something that can be expected in a future release.

Comment: Blender keeps every "undo" move in memory, so there is a finite limit to how many steps you can have. This in mind, you probably want to stop short of using the sum total of your memory and pagefile.

Answer (score 1):

The Undo feature in the blender works by storing a copy of the file inside computer memory for every single thing you do. It means that you really can't have infinite undo steps availible. However, you can increase it to a very high number.

Goto Edit->Preferences->System, and then change the value in "Undo Steps" under "Memory and Limits".